# AntiX linux disable laptop fan

Tags: sensors, fan, antix

I am trying to boot AntiX LiveCD on my old Toshiba A200 laptop with 2 GB of RAM. But when I accidentally launched the "sensors" in the terminal, I saw that the CPU temperature was 70°C! I turned off the laptop and turned it on again, and the fan revved up to the maximum. It turns out that antiX stops the fan? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Is 70 high for this laptop? That seems odd, 70 is barely above "cold" for most CPUs I am familiar with (but please don't take my word for it, I am NOT an expert on hardware). Are you sure the fan was stopped and not just rotating slowly since the CPU wasn't particularly hot? For example, as I type this, my machine is at 69 degrees and the fan is at a pretty low/medium speed. I only have it at max when I approach 90 degrees.

Comment: @terdon, its very high for this laptop, because this temp was in idle

Comment: So? What are the actual temperature ranges? What does `sensors` report as a "high" value? Can you please add the output of `sensors` to your question? It looks like this laptop should have an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU which should be absolutely fine at 70 degrees. For example, [this Core 2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/32243/intel-core2-duo-processor-l7700-4m-cache-1-80-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html) is reported as having a critical temp at 100 degrees. So, please i) tell us your CPU, ii) show the output of sensors including temp and fan speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fan control, especially for old hardware like yours, is a quite obscure matter on Linux;
there are multiple variables to take into account, e.g.:

- kernel version;
- BIOS version;
- BIOS settings;
- *and their combination*;

personally I have never had a such problem, rather the opposite: fan running constantly at 100% with no reason... but in this case, it was "only" annoying;

Coming back to your question:
First, I power off the laptop because high temperature can damage hardware;
Second, I do not rely on temperature measures, rather on acoustic noise, to prove fan running; *I can hear the fan?*
Third, I search for information about **hardware-specific** (that's for your laptop model/manufacturer) fan control software; i.e. [https://sourceforge.net/projects/fnfx/]